# When Wikipedia gives the semimajor axis of the Moon's orbit, which distance does this represent?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, the-moon

The masses of the Earth and Moon are in a ratio of about 81:1, so they can be thought of as orbiting around their common barycenter which is inside the Earth, but about 2/3 of the way to the surface.

When two bodies have somewhat comparable masses, like the Earth-Moon system, and a semimajor axis is reported to many significant figures (e.g. [384,399 km](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon)), is this more like the distance between the centers of the two bodies, or is it more like the Moon's distance from the Earth-Moon barycenter about which it orbits?

Comment: That number is approximately equal to `(405400+362600)/2+399` which is the listed values for `(apogee+perigee)/2+399`. Which seems odd, because the barycenter is 4,671 km from the center of earth. [This article, which I found by searching google for 384399km states that the moon is on average that distance from earth.](http://www.physics.org/article-questions.asp?id=62) Perhaps they used the average distance from earth as the semi-major axis in error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The semi-major axis is the **average** distance between the barycenters of the two bodies, in this case the Moon and the Earth.

We can double check that:

The Earth-Moon distance is known to submeter accuracy. If you have access to the DE or EPM or INPOP ephemerides, you can do all the calculations.
For example, let’s do the calculations with the SPICE library and the de430.bsp data file.

Consider 1 orbit of the Moon that starts at 2018-07-27 00:00:00.000 UTC and ends at 2018-08-23 06:14:14.849 UTC (27.25989 days).

The semi-major axis is 383906.157 km (the average distance from the Earth’s barycenter to the Moon’s barycenter; I calculate it by numerical integration). While if I calculate the distance between the Moon’s barycenter and the EMB, I get 377687.223 km.

If I randomly sample 10000 orbits in the current year (10000 random starting points for the orbit), I get that the semi-major axis ranges from 383684.426 km to 385612.081 km and its average is 384396.002 km *which is quite close to the 384,399 stated in Wikipedia.*

Comment: Please feel free to edit further, I just wanted to give an idea of what I meant. This seems conclusively the answer, thank you very much!

Comment: I added that the sma is the **average** distance.